# In which case should I set the boolean parameter of onLayoutFinished as false?

Tags: android, printing

I am working on print custom document in Android, in  PrintDocumentAdapter  I need to override the function onLayout, I should call onLayoutFinished, I always set the second parameter as true, but the website says

Note: The boolean parameter of the onLayoutFinished() method indicates whether or not the layout content has actually changed since the last request. Setting this parameter properly allows the print framework to avoid unnecessarily calling the onWrite() method, essentially caching the previously written print document and improving performance.

So how can I know whether the layout has been changed from last request, and if it false does it mean it is the same layout with the former layout so why onLayout is called? Which action triggers? I am new to android, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using custom printing, your app determines how the content is laid out and can determine if the file needs to be re-written hence setting it to true. If the content of the file hasn't changed based on the new 'PrintDocumentInfo' then you can set it to false.